# FirebaseCrashlytics(10514): java.io.FileNotFoundException when Integrete within flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

Now I am using Firebase Crashlytics to collection my flutter(2.0.x) app crash report. I am follow the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/usage/) to integereate Firebase Crashlytics into my app. But now after I startup my app, shows this error:

```
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:45289/JjIp3QGyNR8=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 arm...
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514): Settings request failed.
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/gmp/1:532213106096:android:a601d51dae6906622c4275/settings?instance=84c625c86e0207a5d3c0dda0f360c7b47e7e3cfc&build_version=1&display_version=1.0.0&source=1
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpGetRequest.execute(HttpGetRequest.java:80)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:113)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:199)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController$1.then(SettingsController.java:192)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:64)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
E/FirebaseCrashlytics(10514):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
D/FlutterSecureStoragePl(10514): Read: key exists => Running ensureInitStorageCipher
```

when I access the url(`https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/gmp/1:532213106096:android:a601d51dae6906622c4275/settings?instance=84c625c86e0207a5d3c0dda0f360c7b47e7e3cfc&build_version=1&display_version=1.0.0&source=1`) in my local machine, shows 404 not found. Am I missing something? what should I do to fix it?